# Apache Guacamole TOTP log

Tags: tomcat, guacamole, totp

Good morning,

Is it possible with tomcat to have logs produced when a user successfully completes the TOTP connection?

Thanks,

I have already tried to improve the tomcat logs but it does not work as I want it to